# Make variable visible outside callback function - Ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope, ionic2

I'm working with ionic2 and inside `ngOnInit` method of my controller I have this:

```
ngOnInit()
{
   let a;
   this.myAsyncMethod(function(b))  // this is a callback of an async method defined somewhere before ngOnInit()
   {
       a = String(b);  
   }
}
```

I'd like to be able to pass variable `a` to my template and other methods inside the component file.

So I tried in this way:

```
export class myComponent {
c:string;

constructor(....){ // some stuff }
... other methods 

ngOnInit()
{
   let a;
   this.myAsyncMethod(function(b))
   {
       a = String(b);
       this.c = a; // here I get this error in red: EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property 'c' of undefined  
   }
   // if I would put this.c = a here I'll get `c` undefined because I'd be outside the callback function and `a` is not defined yet. 
 }

}
```

in my `template.html` I'd like to print `c` variable doing `{{c}}`

How can I make `c` visible in both `template.html` file and in all other methods I have inside `mycomponent.ts`?

Comment: `let self = this; ` then inside the method `self.c = a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function like:

```
this.myAsyncMethod((b) => {
  this.c = String(b);
});
```

This way `this` will refer to instance of your component.

See also more details about lexical `this` here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this